# Woocommerce: Hide Buy Now Button in Checkout

Tags: button, woocommerce, checkout, disable

I'd like to prevent checkout in WooCommerce if there are certain products in the cart and shipping should go to certain countries. Therefore the notice/error is created but set it to display:none. It should appear and disappear according to the rules. Code goes like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'bbloomer_show_notice_shipping' );
  
function bbloomer_show_notice_shipping(){
?>
  
 <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  
            var countryCode = 'DE';

            selectedCountry = $('select#billing_country').val();
                  
            if( selectedCountry != countryCode ){
                $('.shipping-notice').show();
                $('.form-row.place-order.wc-gzd-place-order').hide();
            }
            else {
                $('.shipping-notice').hide();
                $('.form-row.place-order.wc-gzd-place-order').show();
            }

  
            $('select#billing_country').change(function(){
  
                selectedCountry = $('select#billing_country').val();
                  
                if( selectedCountry != countryCode ){
                    $('.shipping-notice').show();
                    $('.form-row.place-order.wc-gzd-place-order').hide();
                }
                else {
                    $('.shipping-notice').hide();
                    $('.form-row.place-order.wc-gzd-place-order').show();
                }
            });
  
        });
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

$('.shipping-notice').show() and hide() works fine.
Hiding and showing the Buy Now Button works almost fine except on initial loading of the page.

I suspect that $('.form-row.place-order.wc-gzd-place-order').hide(); wants to do its job but the element is not yet existent.

There is a payment gateway in the checkout with a few seconds loading time...the Buy Now Button appears only after this loading is finished.

What could I do to wait until the page has really really completely loaded, including all Ajax etc. and then hide the Button?

Thanks :-)

Comment: From what I can gather from your question it is somewhat like [the following question + the first part of my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69495212/11987538), so using jQuery/AJAX is not really necessary. I also see in your code that you use Germanized for WooCommerce, is this correct? if so, please mention this in your question as the answer can deviate from a default WooCommerce setup, and the answer would not just work 'out-of-the-box' for everyone

Comment: @7uc1f3r: Thanks for your answer. I changed the code to a non-germanized setup. This should work for everyone now.
Before: 'form-row.place-order.wc-gzd-place-order'
After: 'div.place-order button#place_order'

Comment: @7uc1f3r: Your reference (https://stackoverflow.com/a/69495212/11987538) is almost what I needed, thank you. What is missing is the unblocking of the order when the customer selects a country where delivery is not limited. (e.G. Germany -> Yes, place order - Italy -> No, don't place order).

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by adding an extra Action on the hook 'woocommerce_review_order_after_submit', this is executed after the Buy-Now / Place-Order-Button appears, and that solved it. The code above works for me now.